# Merging the more then 2 Json based on unique id in node JS

Tags: node.js

Am new to node JS Merging the more then 2 Json based on unique id  in node JS

```
[
  [
    {
      sourcePguid: '1',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019318': 'General'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      sourcePguid: '2',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019318123': 'General2'
    }
  ]
]
[
  [
    {
      sourcePguid: '1',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019317': '0'
    },
    {
      sourcePguid: '1',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019319': '1'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      sourcePguid: '2',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019311': '0'
    },
    {
      sourcePguid: '2',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019312': '1'
    }
  ]
]
```

Excepted Output :

```
 [
    {
      sourcePguid: '1',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019318': 'General',
       'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019317': '0',
       'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019319': '1'
    },
    {
      sourcePguid: '2',
  'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019318123': 'General2',
       'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019311': '0',
       'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019312': '1'
    },

  ]
```

Kindly if any one help me to achieve the output in node JS.Json will have more than 2 unique values with multiple array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used helper library named [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) for flatting arrays of arrays into one level array

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const json1 = [
  [
    {
      sourcePguid: '1',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019318': 'General'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      sourcePguid: '2',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019318123': 'General2'
    }
  ]
];
const json2 = [
  [
    {
      sourcePguid: '1',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019317': '0'
    },
    {
      sourcePguid: '1',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019319': '1'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      sourcePguid: '2',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019311': '0'
    },
    {
      sourcePguid: '2',
      'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019312': '1'
    }
  ]
];

const mergedJsons = [...json1, ...json2];
const result = _.flattenDepth(mergedJsons)
  .reduce((combined, current) => {
    const combinedObjectIndex = combined.findIndex(lookingFor => lookingFor.sourcePguid === current.sourcePguid);
    if (combinedObjectIndex < 0) {
      // if object is new, lets add it to result array
      combined.push(current);
    } else {
      // if object exists in array, lets merge them together
      combined[combinedObjectIndex] = {...combined[combinedObjectIndex], ...current};
    }

    return combined;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

And the ouput is:

```
[
  {
    sourcePguid: '1',
    'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019318': 'General',
    'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019317': '0',
    'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019319': '1'
  },
  {
    sourcePguid: '2',
    'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019318123': 'General2',
    'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019311': '0',
    'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000019312': '1'
  }
]
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to use external library, here is my `flat` method, and instead of using `_.flattenDepth(mergedJsons)` you use `flat(mergedJsons)`

```
function flat(arr: any[], ...arrays: any[]) {
  if (arrays.length === 0) {
    return arr.reduce((total, curr) => {
      if (Array.isArray(curr)) {
        total.push(...flat([], ...curr));
      } else {
        total.push(curr);
      }
      return total;
    }, []);
  }
  if (Array.isArray(arrays[0])) {
    arr = [].concat(arr, arrays[0]);
  } else {
    arr.push(arrays[0]);
  }
  arrays.splice(0, 1);
  return flat(arr, ...arrays);
}
```

Comment: Thats not a good advice. There is no reason to require a whole librarie for a simple concat. Thats the problem with mordern "development": Use librarie xyz...

Comment: Ye you right, but if someone have trouble with simple concat, then is much simpler to use external library for that to understand what's happened in code and how to reach his goal instead of reinventing the wheel. All is up to developer that he want to use it or not

Comment: @DamianPlewa you could do that with a simple `.flat()`. And have much less overhead than include a whole librarie...

Comment: @Marc you are right. I didn't know about that, thank you. But .flat() is available since node 11.0, so if someone is using earlier version of node, then he need to use workaround like library/polyfill or selfcoded method

Comment: @DamianPlewa In a "enterprise environment" you should allways use a stable LTS version wich is currently "12.16.3" and even "newcomer" use a version higher than 12.x.x Only if you use a version before 2018...